# SageMaker Studio: Importing custom package

Tags: python, package, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I'm using SageMaker Studio notebook and am having trouble importing my custom package.

When I'm in the terminal in SageMaker Studio, my package file (dblogin.py) is in this path:

```
/home/sagemaker-user/DBPackage
```

Within the notebook, I have the following code:

```
sys.path.append('/root/DBPackage')
import DBPackage.dblogin
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DBPackage'
```

I also tried adding this path but with no luck

```
sys.path.append('/home/sagemaker-user/DBPackage')
```